# How to read a csv file into something like a "record" data type?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

*For Python 3.4.0*

Hey everyone,
I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
string1;value1
string2;value2
string3;value3
```

What I wanna do is getting this csv file into some kind of "record" data type, so that I can e.g. look for *stringX* in *stringbig* and, if *stringX* is found, then add *+1* to *valueX*.

What is the easiest way to code that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make rows into `namedtuple`s. Here's a simple example:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

Record = namedtuple('Record', ['product', 'part_number', 'category'])

mydict = defaultdict(dict)
with open('inventory.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    for rec in map(Record._make, csv.reader(inf)):
        print(rec.part_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the builtin `csv` module and a simple python dictionary:

```
import csv 

records = {}
with open('/path/to/your/file.csv','rb') as fileobj:
    reader = csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter=';')
    for key, value in reader:
        records[key] = int(value)
```

Then you can easily update the `valueX` for `stringX` by doing:

```
records[stringX] = records.get(stringX, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DictReader for that:

CSV:

```
Name;Value
string1;0
string2;20
string3;12
```

Python:

```
import csv
with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in r:
      if 'string2' in row['Name']:
          row['Value'] += 1
          print(row)
          
{'Value': 21, 'Name': 'string2'}
```

Comment: Nearly seems to work, but one error: "Can't convert "int" object to str implicitly - I think, column "value" is read as a string, but should usally be read as an integer... Any idea? EDIT: Simply added a "row['Value'] = int(row['Value'])" - now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AtillaW. do you have the same file structure as shown in my answer? do you have headings in you file for DictReader to work first line should be headers -> Name;Value

Comment: Yes, exactly the same structure.

Comment: Ah could be a reason: 3.4.0 my one.

Comment: @AtillaW. should not be a problem.. It is a simple code. I bet if you copy and paste data and the code it will work.